# Sorting Data in Angular in Ascending/Descending on click of a button

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5, angular6, angular7

I have a `(click)` that calls a `sortUser()` function that sorts the data.
My HTML looks like this.

```js
let isAscendingSort: Boolean = true;
sortUser() {
    console.log('sorting!'); //just to check if sorting is beng called
    this.items.sort((item1: any, item2: any) => this.compare(item1, item2));
  }
  // Sort
  compare(item1: any, item2: any): number {
    let compValue = 0;
      compValue = item1.attributes.fullName.localeCompare(item2.attributes.fullName, 'en', {
        sensitivity: 'base'
      });
    console.log(compValue);
    if (!this.isAscendingSort) {
      compValue = compValue * -1;
    }
    return compValue;
  }
```

```html
<button (click)="sortData()">Sort Data</button>
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
{{items.attributes.fullName}}
</div>
```

**What I want is It should sort Ascending/Descending on click of a button**.But it'll only sort the data based ascending oreder only.I dont know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are forgetting to flip the switch:

```
private isAscendingSort: boolean = false;

sortUser() {
  console.log('sorting!'); // just to check if sorting is being called
  this.isAscendingSort = !this.isAscendingSort; // you missed this

  this.items.sort((item1: any, item2: any) => this.compare(item1, item2));
}
```

Comment: Worked Like a charm...Thanks a tonne. This is what I call as a silly mistake :).